# What's a good way to create multiple dataframes of different row length from one dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
df  
Index   Fruit
1       Apple
2       Banana
3       Peach
4       Watermelon
5       Apricot
```

I want to create 3 dataframes from this, using the indexes =`[[1,4],[1,3,5],[1,2,4]]`. I want to be able to call these dataframes by the value of these index keys (?, not too familiar with dictionaries but i feel like this is a good time to use it), such that A : [1,4], B : [1,3,5], C : [1,2,4].

The final dataframes should look like the following:

```
df_1    
Index   Fruit
1       Apple
4       Watermelon

df_2    
Index   Fruit
1       Apple
3       Peach
5       Apricot

df_3    
Index   Fruit
1       Apple
2       Banana
4       Watermelon
```

What's the best way to iterate through df to generate these dataframes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a *dict comprehension*:

```
df = df.set_index('Index')
df

            Fruit
Index            
1           Apple
2          Banana
3           Peach
4      Watermelon
5         Apricot

idx
[[1, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 2, 4]]

d = {'df_{}'.format(i) : df.loc[x] for i, x in enumerate(idx, 1)}

d.keys()
dict_keys(['df_2', 'df_1', 'df_3'])
```

You can use `d` to index into the appropriate dataframe using `d['df_*']`.

---

If you don't want `Index` as the index, do a `reset_index` call:

```
d = {'df_{}'.format(i) : df.loc[x].reset_index() for i, x in enumerate(idx, 1)}
```

Comment: What is `idx`??